# Is it safe to smoke with oak treated for oak wilt?

Tags: barbecue, smoking

Trying to find a source for wood logs to smoke with Ii found a guy selling oak on craigslist but he says it has been treated for oak wilt. Is it safe to smoke with?

Comment: I am not posting this as a answer as I can't find a direct reference. However, after much reading, oak wilt is typically treated with a fungicide. I would not recommend cooking with any wood that has been treated with chemicals as you may smell it, taste it, and more importantly become sick from it.

Comment: @ChingChong It sounds similar, but it's not a duplicate. In the other question, it was treated wood - that's wood that's had things applied to it as part of making it into a finished product. In this case, it's a tree that was treated for a disease while alive. It might be with fungicide as Cindy mentioned (in which case the answer is similar - it potentially contains hazardous chemicals). But oak wilt is also commonly treated simply in preventative ways - sealing off any wounds on the tree to keep it from getting infected. So a full answer will cover more than just chemical treatments.